# Need an article about multithreading in i7 processor

Tags: intel-core-i7

I need an article about multi-threading in intel i7 processors, I am searching from hours and can't find anything!.
please give me some links or any informations.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of googling:

http://digitalconqurer.com/reviews/processors/multi-threading-in-intel-core-i7-processors/

http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi10/cse141/mp.pdf